# UICollectionView - Add action to footer view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, action, footer

I have a UICollectionView with a footer view. Footer view class is created by me. Footer view is a button that I want to put an action. I tried to add one action but nothing happened when I pressed the button. Please help me.

My code:

**FViewController.m**

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter) {

    FooterCollectionReusableView *footerview = [[FooterCollectionReusableView alloc] init];
    footerview = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"FooterView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        [footerview.todoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(todosPush:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        reusableview = footerview;
    }

    return reusableview;
}

-(IBAction)todosPush:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"todosPush");
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    TipoEjercicioViewController *tipo = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TipoEjercicioView"];
    tipo.ejercicio = 22;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tipo animated:YES];
}
```

**FooterCollectionReusableView.h**

```
@interface FooterCollectionReusableView : UICollectionReusableView

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton * todoButton;

@end
```

Comment: try after removing `UITapGestureRecognizer`

Comment: I tried but nothing happen....

Comment: are you used break point? is your todosPush is called or not

Comment: try this `return (UICollectionReusableView *)footerview;`

Comment: I tried it, doesn't work

Comment: you are not initializing `FooterCollectionReusableView`

Comment: I have written:         FooterCollectionReusableView *footerview = [[FooterCollectionReusableView alloc] init];
        footerview = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"FooterView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: update your question with some FooterCollectionReusableView code

Comment: no, the code inside FooterCollectionReusableView.m and FooterCollectionReusableView.h

Comment: FooterCollectionReusableView.m haven't got any code

Comment: is you connected `todoButton` with button in storyboard

Comment: I forget connect button ouch :( (basic error) oh yes it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Add following lines

```
FooterCollectionReusableView *footerview = (FooterCollectionReusableView *)[collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"FooterView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

and

```
return (UICollectionReusableView *)footerview;
```

Also check is your todoButton is connected to Button in storyboard or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is what happened:

> is you connected todoButton with button in storyboard?

I forget connect de button :( now it works

Thank you Lalit Kumar

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    CGSize footersize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 20);
    return footersize;
}
```